# Google Cloud Platform registration

Tags: google-cloud-storage, payment

During the registration process on Google Cloud Platform I filled up 3 times the wrong phone number and I got 3 payment transactions from my card, each one of 1 USD.

It means that you can just set card number with valid CVC and press "ok" button.

Is this ok or I missed about this charge in The Terms of Service ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty common for providers like Google to put a small hold on a credit card to test that it is valid. If you use a debit card this will actually decrease the available balance on the account, but it should not be finalized and the money will not actually be taken.

I suggest you [get in touch with Google's billing team](https://support.google.com/cloud/#topic=3340599&contact=1&ts=6075738,6078412,6078045), who will be able to track down the payment and double check everything is correct.